# Reed switch passive interupt for garage heater when door is open (using NC switch)?

Tags: reed-switch, thermostat

I'm trying to prevent my garage heater from running while the garage door is open to prevent it from attempting to heat the entire neighborhood if/when the door is accidentally left open.

I have a wireless garage door sensor ([Honeywell 5816MN](https://firealarmresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Ademco-5816MN-Door-Window-Transmitter.pdf)) wired to an [external magnetic reed switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004PARDRO) already installed for the alarm system that triggers whenever the garage door is opened.  I was hoping to re-use the same equipment if possible, since it's already mounted to the door for monitoring.

What I'd like to do is interrupt the heating wire from the thermostat to the heater whenever the door is opened.

The problem is the magnetic reed switch already uses the Normally Open terminals as the wireless sensor identifies an alarm state when continuity is interrupted.

**Requirements:**

1) When door is closed, heater can run, when door is open, heater cannot run

2) Must either use the NC terminal of magnetic switch, or coexist on NO terminal with the existing alarm wireless sensor

3) No power available for active electronic components (relays, etc)

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Since it is impossible to prove a negative, I will make this a comment. No, I don't think that what you want to do is possible. I think that connecting the furnace/thermostat to the magnetic reed switch in any **direct** fashion will probably destroy the wireless sensor. You need to work harder to find some power and be willing to add components.

Comment: Your description of the existing equipment in incomplete and unclear. What voltage and current does the thermostat use? By "re-use" do you mean "abandon the existing use and use for another purpose" or "add a new function to the existing system? Adding an existing function does not seem possible. Re-purposing may be possible. I am voting to close the question as unclear. Since you have not proposed a specific design, it seems like you need detailed do-it-yourself instructions rather than answers to a specific design question. There is a home improvement stack exchange for that.

Comment: @CharlesCowie - by "re-use" I'm talking about using the existing magnetic switch IN PLACE.  Basically, I was trying to figure out how to use the other switch  terminal (NC) to accomplish a second function, without over-engineering a power/relay type design.  My fallback solution is to install a second switch, mounted such that the existing magnet activates both switches and both are isolated circuits.  It just seemed like there might be a way to avoid installing another switch.

Comment: Attempting to one switch for two functions is likely to damage one or more of the items involved.